# change size of jcrop selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins

I'm trying to adjust the `selection box` of jcrop when the user enters a width and height and click on `submit`.

I have put an example here: http://pixelbypixel.comli.com/jcrop/

jcrop plugin here: http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php

If the user clicks on `submit`, the `selection box` is getting the `width` and `height` that the user enters but after the user tries to move the box it changes back to the size that it was before `submit`.

This is the code I have written to do it:

```
/* jcrop when page loads */
var jcrop_api;
function initJcrop(oImg){
        oImg.Jcrop({},function(){
           jcrop_api = this;
           jcrop_api.animateTo([100,100,400,300]);
        });
    };      
jQuery(function(jQuery){
    initJcrop(jQuery('#jcrop_target'));
});

/* box number when page loads */
function showCoords(c){
    jQuery('#w').val(c.w);
    jQuery('#h').val(c.h);
};

/* size when submit */
jQuery('.update-size').click(function(){
    var ancho = jQuery('#w').val();
    var altura = jQuery('#h').val();
    jQuery('.jcrop-holder > div:nth-child(1)').css('height', altura);
    jQuery('.jcrop-holder > div:nth-child(1)').css('width', ancho);
});
```

And this is the markup:

```
<img src="img/test.jpg" id="jcrop_target">
<div>
    <p>Define your own dimensions in CM:</p>
    <form>
        <label>Width: <input type="text" size="4" id="w" name="w" value="360"></label>
        <label>Height: <input type="text" size="4" id="h" name="h" value="360"></label>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="update-size">submit</a>
    </form>
</div>
```

Any idea what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On submit event, you need to set 'setSelect' property of the jCrop like this:

```
jcrop_api.setSelect([0,0,ancho,altura]);
```

See this example and you will get more idea:
http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=advanced

Comment: Thanks, it works but is it possible to make the change of size in the same position? it resets to the position x0 and y0

Comment: Yes it is possible, for that you need to get values of x and y variables in showCoords() function and then pass those variables with setSelect() option.